# Convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Why does the $\lim \sum{n^{(1/n)}-1}$ diverge as $n\rightarrow \infty$? I suspected it would converge as $\lim {n^{(1/n)}}=1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ but computation show otherwise. So, now I am trying to show the partial sums are unbounded but didnt get far.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the rule. Just because the limit of the sequence is zero does not mean the series converges. We only know two things... if the series converges then the limit of the sequence is zero, and if the limit of the sequence is non-zero then the series diverges. You cannot swap the conditional backwards.

Comment: Anyway to apply this criteria you'd need $\sum (n^{1/n}-1)$ and not $\sum n^{1/n}-1$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: for $n\ge3$ we have
$$n^{1/n}>e^{1/n}>1+\frac1n\ .$$

Comment: The most straightforward approach. I like it. Wish I thought of it. Perhaps for the sake of the asker you should elaborate on the proof a bit.

Answer (score 0):

$$
n^{1/n}=1+a_n\quad \text{with}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0.
$$
Taking logarithms
$$
\frac{\log n}{n}=\log(1+a_n)\sim a_n\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty
$$
and $\sum(\log n)/n$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [comparison test](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/sequences_series_approx_calc/convergence-divergence-tests/v/comparison-test) here, and find a series to compare with yours.

Answer (score 0):

$n^{1/n} = e^{\ln(n)/n} - 1$ is positive and equivalent to the positive term $\ln(n)/n$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$. (Just expand $\exp$ at the first order in $0$.) Not $\ln(n)/n$ is the general term of a Bertrand series which is in this case divergent. By equivalence, the series of general term $n^{1/n} = e^{\ln(n)/n} - 1$ is also divergent.